# Xbox Music only "matches" ~70% of the songs on most of my albums. How can I make it recognize the other songs?

Tags: windows-8, mp3, music, cloud, xbox-music

When Xbox Music matches a song on my PC, it adds it to my "Xbox Music cloud". I can stream music from this cloud to all of my other devices.

The problem is, it fails to match at least 2-3 on most of my albums. How can I make it match all of my songs, so that I can stream them everywhere?

Comment: Why is this flagged as off-topc? It's about the Xbox Music app for Windows 8, it has nothing to do with an actual Xbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found instructions [here](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-match-music-144730). You can do it manually, album-by-album.

1. Right click on the album you watch to match.
2. Select "More" from the right-click menu.
3. Select "Match Album Info".
4. Follow the dialog. For songs whose name doesn't match the name in Microsoft's database, you will have to choose the correct name from a list.

Edit: This is a long and arduous process, and does not work for all albums. I estimate it will take at least 5-10 hours before I finish matching all of my albums. Not only that, but "matched" albums do not propagate to my other machines (i.e., I would have to repeat the matching process on each machine), which share the same music library via SkyDrive. This is not a workable solution by any stretch of the imagination. If anyone has a better solution, I would love to hear it.

Comment: You might be able to use something like mp3tag (there are others I forgot the name of, search for mp3 or id3 tag editors) for a more automated retagging of your music. However, its database might not be 100% compatible with Microsoft's one.

Comment: @Bob: I keep my tags in pristine condition with MusicBrainz Picard.

Comment: I don't think the tags really matter that much. I saw a song last night that had a space between words (as set by MusicBrainz Picard) and Xbox Music was expecting a hyphen. I hope in time it gets better, but for the moment the app is pretty much 70% of what it could be.